# octopress the first commit

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I am newbie about octopress, so i can face some problems. At the beginning, I cloned the octopress repository, and I created a repository is called OctoBlog, and after that I

```
rake setup_github_pages
```

and

```
rake generate
rake deploy
```

At this point, everything seems great. I did every step the tutorial which is on octopress offical website, but when I want to

```
git add .
git commit -m 'your message'
git push origin source
```

commit the codes, there occured a problem is

```
error: src refspec source does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:enderahmetyurt/OctoBlog.git'
```

and I realized that there is no master branch on my repository, and I don't know how I can create a new master brach. Is it set itself when we create a new repository on github?

In shortly i want to learn, How can I commit my octopress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `git push origin master` instead of  `git push origin source`. If you want to use the source branch, you should put your branch to track it and do a `git push origin source`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is here:

> At the beginning, I cloned the octopress repository, and I created a repository is called OctoBlog

The [Octopress Github deploy documentation](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) tells us to use `username.github.com` as the repo name for an Octopress blog, so yours would be `enderahmetyurt.github.com`. The Github Pages Guide to [User, Organization and Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) tells us that User pages **must** use the `username/username.github.com` naming scheme. You need to rename your repo and try again :) FWIW, I knew the answer because I named my repo `username` on the first try... Doh!